# Binding Setting Property but UI not updating. Can I debug within referenced project/control?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

I have a custom control with bindings like below

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}">
    <me:MarkdownEditor 
        Options="{Binding Path=Options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I find that binding (`Window1.Options`) is being set (after stepping through code in debug mode), the markdown editor options (supposed to set Fonts, Colors etc) does not get set, or at least the UI does not update. I want to bug whats happening with in the `MarkdownEditor.xaml.cs` but thats another (referenced) project. How can I verify that the `MarkdownEditor.Options` is being set at least?

I have actually tested that the `MarkdownEditor` side is working by the below

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Options" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0" />
        <me:MarkdownEditor Options="{Binding Options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So the difference is the latter is a `MarkdownEditor` just in a `Grid` in a `Window`. The one failing is a `MarkdownEditor` within a `TabControl` bound to a `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`

**Visual Studio Solution Replicating The Problem**

I am not really good at explaining things, so a simple project I made up minus all the unnecessary noise uploaded to **[media fire](http://www.mediafire.com/?d88dsine5vug5gz)** so you can take a look at whats wrong

The video showing the problem on **[Screenr](http://screenr.com/hQc)**

With just a simple usage, editor in a window/grid.

[image]

the binding works ok

Then when used in conjunction with `TabControl` bound to `ObservableCollection<EditorTabViewModel>`, the binding works as shown in the 2 `TextBox`es updating its values. but the editor does not update

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading Kent Boogaart's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230698/whats-the-difference-between-dependency-property-setvalue-setcurrentvalue) question I think that the right place to change SetValue to SetCurrentValue isn't in the CLR Property but in the constructor for MarkDownEditor.

```
public MarkdownEditor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Options = new MarkdownEditorOptions();
    this.SetCurrentValue(OptionsProperty, new MarkdownEditorOptions());
    DataContext = this;
}
```

In fact, this will work just as good without this.SetCurrentValue also since Options will be set through the Binding.

To verify that your Binding has in fact been overwritten by SetValue you can add this code in some event for TabUsage (e.g PreviewMouseRightButtonDown for the FontSize TextBox) and the Binding will start to work again.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MarkdownEditor.MarkdownEditor editor = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualChild<MarkdownEditor.MarkdownEditor>(this);
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Options");
    binding.Source = this;
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    editor.SetBinding(MarkdownEditor.MarkdownEditor.OptionsProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: YAY, it works! You're great @Meleak, learnt alot from you! Thanks

Comment: HBut I still don't really get `SetCurrentValue()` ... I guess time to re-read & digest the other question ...

Comment: @jiewmeng: Hehe sure thing :) Nice control you're working on btw

Comment: thanks. I was trying to replicate WMD Markdown Editor in WPF/C#. Its also a practice project, I thought it would be a relatively easy project, turns out complicated lol ...